# How to best check if the contents of two objects are identical?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array of cached objects that I retrieve using NSCoding and NSKeyedUnarchiver. These have have many properties.

I now need to check if the contents of an object I create is identical to any of the cached objects contents in the array.
I of course cannot check if the references to the objects are equal using containsObject, but I can check if their contents are identical. I know how to achieve the end result, but what's best practice in this case? I would want it to take as little time as possible.

And keep in mind that the objects are only identical if all their properties match.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the `isEqual:` and `hash` methods on the class. The implementation of `isEqual:` should compare all properties.

Once you have those two methods properly implemented you can make use of collection methods such as `NSArray containsObject:` or `NSArray indexOfObjects:`, etc.

Comment: So its necessary to override isEqual: and hash?

Comment: It's not necessary to override -hash (as NSObject's pretty good about keeping it in line), but isEqual: is recommended.

Comment: It's very important that if two objects come out as equal, they must have the same hash value.

Comment: Mike Ash has a nice [Friday Q&A about `-isEqual:` and hashing](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html).